# Deserialize JSON only if it specifies a value for a value type property

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

If I have a DTO class containing value type properties, how can I idiomatically use Newtonsoft to deserialize JSON to my DTO class while ensuring that the JSON defines the value type, possibly containing the `default` value for the type?  So far the methods I have seen rely on checking if the value is the `default` value, however, this is not a suitable solution when the `default` value is also a valid value for the property.

## Example

```cs
public class MyDto
{
    public bool MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

| JSON | Can deserialize to `MyDto` |
| --- | --- |
| `{"MyProp": true}` | true |
| `{"MyProp": false}` | true |
| `{}` | false |

## Current solution

Currently I use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute` and declare the type as nullable, but this only works during model binding (instead of any deserialization), and leads to excessive use of `!` when referencing the property.

```cs
public class MyDto
{
    [Required]
    public bool? MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen, when JSON is `{}` ?

Comment: The deserializer should not succeed.  If it's an `ApiController` model, the client should receive a 400, if it's a `JsonConvert` call, it should throw.

Comment: We need to see your ApiController and even a fully reproducible example. Otherwise it is very difficult to figure out what the problem actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the [JsonPropertyAttribute Required](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyRequired.htm) property:

```
public class MyDto
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public bool MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

This results in an exception when the JSON being deserialized does not contain the specified property (`MyProp`). For example, the following:

```
string json = "{\"MyProp\": true}";
MyDto myDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDto>(json);
Console.WriteLine(myDto.MyProp);

json = "{\"MyProp\": false}";
myDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDto>(json);
Console.WriteLine(myDto.MyProp);

json = "{}";
myDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDto>(json);
Console.WriteLine(myDto.MyProp);
```

Gives the result:

```
True
False
Run-time exception (line 17): Required property 'MyProp' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the JSON using JSON Schema ([Newtonsoft.Json.Schema](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/)) like this:

```
public class MyDto
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public bool MyProp { get; set; }
}


var generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
var schema = generator.Generate(typeof(MyDto));
var dto = JObject.Parse(@"{ 'MyProp': true }");
bool isValid = dto.IsValid(schema);
Console.WriteLine(isValid); // True

dto = JObject.Parse(@"{}");
isValid = dto.IsValid(schema);
Console.WriteLine(isValid); // False
```